# How to pass remaining scroll distance of UIScrollView to parent UIScrollView when end is reached?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView`. The `UITableView` is at the bottom of the `UIScrollView`. The height of the tableview is set to the height of the scrollview. Above the `UITableView` are some more views (that's why I have a surrounding `UIScrollView`)

When the `UIScrollView` is scrolled to the bottom, I want my `UITableView` to take over the scroll. I know that iOS is taking care of this by itself, but it cancels the scroll and only scrolls the `UITableView` when you perform a next scroll.

Is there any way of knowing the distance a `UIScrollView` still needs to scroll when it reaches the end of its content?

If so I could just perform `setContentOffset` to the `UITableView`.